# Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Merge replication deleting records on subscriber

Tags: sql-server-2005

I created a simple merge replication.  I used the default settings to create the publication which was creating a script to create the snapshot that Occurs every 14 day(s) at 12:05:00 AM.   First, I am not sure why it needs to run every 14 days.  Second, after researching for hours, I could not figure out how to not replicate deletes.   Whenever I create the subscription and run the script, it creates a mirror image of everything that the publisher has and deletes any records in the subscriber that were not in the publisher.   I need both publisher and subscriber to be merged without any deletes...Just inserts and updates.

I am a beginner when it comes to Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2005.   If I need to modify any scripts or stored procedures could you please let me know how to do that.   Whenever I try to modify a script, it asks me to save it to a file and I am not sure how to get it updated with the changes in the database.

Thanks
-Dimitry

Comment: I think I figured out why the database at the subscriber side was being overwritten.  I had Action if name is in use under Article Properties set to "Drop existing object and create a new one" instead of "Keep existing object unchanged."   

I am now running into different problems.  Every time I run the merge, it gives me a call sp_MSsetconflicttable error.  I did research on the error and it said something about Rowguid problem.   I see the Rowguid is created on the publisher side but how do I create them on the subscriber side if the database is not being dropped and recreated?